# Calling controller method using Ajax not working in Magento

Tags: ajax, magento-1.7

I am calling controller method using Ajax in my custom module. See my ajax call code-

```
 var btnUpload=$('#upload');
    var status=$('#status');   

 new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
                        action:"<?php echo getUrl('character/adminhtml_ajax/fileUpload') ?>", /* module/controller/action */
                        name: 'uploadfile',
                        onSubmit: function(file, ext){
                             if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){ 

                                status.text('Only JPG, PNG or GIF files are allowed');
                                return false;
                            }
                            status.text('Uploading...');
                        },
                        onComplete: function(file, response){

                            status.text('');

                            if(response==="success"){
                                $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="./uploads/'+file+'" alt="" /><br />'+file).addClass('success');
                            } else{
                                $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text(response).addClass('error');
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

But it gives me HTML of **system->configuration** page in admin of magento in response and not calling controller method "**fileUpload**".

this is my controller method-

```
<?php

class Assel_Character_Adminhtml_AjaxController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function fileUploadAction()
    {
        echo "this is controller method";
    }
}
```

Why this is happening..?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use with `<?php echo getUrl('character/adminhtml/ajax/fileUpload') ?>`
and ajax controller file should be 'AjaxController.php' in 'adminhtml' directory.

Comment: Hello @ Rakesh.Thanks for reply. I have already done what you told  but redirecting to admin page of system->configuration.